# How to Disable Menu items in evince

Tags: 14.04, pdf, evince

I want to disable menu items for a user for evince such as:

1. File: Open , Open a Copy,Save, etc
2. View : Side Pane: Annotation and Bookmarks
3. Help : Help and about Us.

Comment: which file contains these options and how to disable

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no watertight solution. The menu entries are in

```
shell/traditional-menus.ui
shell/evince-menus.ui
```

and

```
shell/evince.css
```

is also interesting.

A solution could be:

1. Get the source code and install the dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get source evince
   sudo apt-get build-dep evince
   ```
2. Change the menu files and/or the css
3. Reconfigure with an alternative path for the installation, e.g. `/usr/local/restricted_user`

   ```
   sudo ./configure --prefix /usr/local/restricted_user
   ```
4. Re-compile Evince

   ```
   sudo make distclean
   sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc
   ```
5. Install the deb package
6. Create a desktop file in the user's home directory

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/evince.desktop /home/restricted_user/.local/share/applications
   sudo chown restricted_user:restricted_user /home/restricted_user/.local/share/applications/vince.desktop
   ```

   and use the re-compiled version for `Exec=`
7. Make sure that the user has no longer access to `/usr/bin/evince`